# Django Model field to populate another field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, web-development-server

I'm back again, I've been on this for more than 48 hours, still couldn't find a response to this.

I have this model.

The Position table has Site Engineer, Site Manager, HVAC Engineer, etc

Engineers have only one position each, and I want the manager field to be populated only if the Engineer created has a position Site Manager. If an Engineer is created, the manager field will be a dropdown list of Engineers who have the Site Manager position.

```
from django.db import models

class Position(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Site Engineer')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Engineers(models.Model):

    region = (
       ('SS', 'South-South'), ('SW', 'South-West'), ('SE', 'South-East'),
       ('NE', 'North-East'), ('NW', 'North-West'), ('NC', 'North-Central'),
    )

    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='Leave Blank', unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=11)
    position = models.ForeignKey(Position, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    workarea = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=region)
    manager = models.CharField(verbose_name='Site Manager', max_length=80, default=None)


    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.username = self.firstname +'.'+self.lastname
        self.manager = self.firstname +' '+self.lastname

        super(Engineers, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            
    def __str__(self):
        return self.firstname + ' ' + self.lastname
```

This code only fills the manager field with the name of the Engineers, even if they are not Site Managers.

Please help

Comment: Why do you need the manager field as a dropdown? you can make another table there the list of managers will be shown. Besides You can see the site manager list in the template without changing in manager field. You have made the database complicated. Make it simple.

Comment: Thank you @Jafoor the aim is to make it simple. Please help with any suggestions to improve this. I have thought to create a Site_Manager table, but still don't know who to go about this.

Comment: you can give me your git repo. After seeing your project details I will design you a databse.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this by editing the manager field as:

```
manager = models.ForeignKey('self' , on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, db_index=False, related_name='Manager')
```

As seen here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#module-django.db.models.fields.related.

Be sure to set the db_index to false though.